# ASP .NET MVC - Click on href link and update a table (ActionLink)

Tags: action, href, actionlink

I have a partial view with this code:

```
<a href="http://www.teste.net/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>
Model.Link)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Titulo)<a>
```

This render a link in a View so the users can click on link and access the html pages outside application. It works fine.

But I need update a table when a user click in link so I need trigger an Action.

I've tried using this code:

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Titulo).ToString(), "GetHtmlFile", new { id = Model.ArtigoID , path = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Link) })
```

so the Action **GetHtmlFile** will need render html files in this way:

```
public ActionResult GetHtmlPage(int id, string path)
 {
      updateTableArticle(id); 
      return new FilePathResult(path, "text/html");
 }
```

It works, but there's a problem. The html files are in relative path so many pictures aren't  shown and many links are broken...

There is no easier way to click on the link and update the table in this cenario whithout must render the html files as a view ?